# Configure AWS CLI to handle multiple profiles plugged on different partitions and endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have several accounts on the AWS Cloud, and some accounts on other clouds with aws compliant APIs (like Outscale)

I was given the following `~/.aws/models/endpoints.json` that defines available services on the outscale cloud

```
{
  "partitions" : [ 
    {
      "defaults": {
        "hostname": "{service}.{region}.{dnsSuffix}",
        "protocols": [
          "https"
        ],
        "signatureVersions": [
          "v4"
        ]
      },
      "dnsSuffix": "outscale.com",
      "partition": "osc",
      "partitionName": "Outscale",
      "regionRegex": "^(cloudgouv|us|eu|ap)\\-\\w+\\-\\d+$",
      "regions": {
        "eu-west-2": {
          "description": "EU (Paris)"
        },
        "cloudgouv-eu-west-1": {
          "description": "CloudGouv EU (Paris)"
        },
        "us-east-2": {
          "description": "US East (NY)"
        },
        "us-west-1": {
          "description": "US West (California)"
        },
        "ap-northeast-1": {
          "description": "Japan (Tokyo)"
        }
      },
      "services": {
        [...]
        "s3": {
          "endpoints": {
            "eu-west-2": {"hostname": "oos.eu-west-2.outscale.com","signatureVersions": ["s3v4"]},
            "cloudgouv-eu-west-1": {"hostname": "oos.cloudgouv-eu-west-1.outscale.com","signatureVersions": ["s3v4"]},
            "us-east-2": {"hostname": "oos.us-east-2.outscale.com","signatureVersions": ["s3"]},
            "us-west-1": {"hostname": "oos.us-west-1.outscale.com","signatureVersions": ["s3"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "version" : 3
}
```

I have also recovered after digging from the aws sdk go repository, the list of [some default aws endpoints](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/+/refs/tags/v1.16.24/models/endpoints/endpoints.json) (otherwise with just this in my `~/.aws/models/endpoints.json.` it would break my attempts to use the regular aws APIs)

I don't understand how I can make all my AWS profiles work (I have tried to merge both default partitions in the same endpoints.json file, to no avail)

Here are my profiles

```
# Regular AWS CLoud
[profile aws-prod]
region = eu-central-1
output = json

# Cloud Outscale
[profile outscale-prod]
region = cloudgouv-eu-west-1
output = json

[profile outscale-dev]
region = eu-west-2
output = json
```

How can I configure my aws cli, so the "outscale" profiles would actually use the "osc" partition while my other aws profiles would use the "aws" partition ?

I would be able to do something like

```
BUCKET=xxx
REGION=yyy
AWS_PROFILE=[AWS or Outscale profile]
aws s3api create-bucket \
    --profile $AWS_PROFILE
    --bucket $BUCKET \
    --region $REGION \
    --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=$REGION
```

and that it would work using either the

Comment: In the command, if you specify both `--profile` and `--endpoint`, it will work, right? But you want it to work with only `--profile`, is it?

Comment: Yes, because the endpoint will be different for every aws-compatible service, so it's quite a bit of pain to change all commands